# Energy Saving on Ubuntu PC's (not Laptops!)

Tags: power-management

1. Can I use software designed for power saving on laptops on Home PC. (not a laptop)
2. Or maybe someone could suggest alternative tools designed for saving power on PC desktop?
3. What are the other steps required to reduce energy consuming under Ubuntu?

Comment: -all the power saving options Jupiter used to be able to change are built into the kernel. - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter The list here is comprehensive.

Comment: I am not looking for a Jupiter alternative.I would like to know if those apps are useful for non-laptop computer to reduce energy connsuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes!
2. No, not needed.
3. Easy: just type the following command to get a list of all power-related applications in the Ubuntu repository:

   ```
    apt-cache search power | grep --ignore-case --invert-match powerful | grep --ignore-case --invert-match powerpc | grep --ignore-case power
   ```

**Free extra:** *Turning off and unplugging your PC not only reduces its power consumption to 0% but also raises its security level to 100%!*

## ;-)

Comment: Accepting the answer would be appreciated as it's 100% correct and an upvote for the laugh you had would be tremendous!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question and not being too lazy to read it up to the end! I know it doesn't make much difference when you are using only one computer but this information may be useful for large companies using a lot of machines for business use.

Comment: Muzaffar, the hardware used in PCs is not that different from those on laptops (and I'm old enough to remember a monitor *turning itself off automatically* had a big *wow* factor 25 years ago... (Yes, I'm an old fart!) ;-)